# Make select element truly unfocusable

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, focus, tabindex

I have been trying to make a select element unfocusable. Multiple sources suggest to set the `tabIndex` to `-1`. That is what I have attempt, but it failed.

Consider the following example:

```js
function addEv(id, event, message)
{
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function(){
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = message;
  });
}
addEv('select', 'focus', 'select focus');
addEv('select', 'blur', 'select blur');

addEv('span', 'focus', 'span focus');
addEv('span', 'blur', 'span blur');

addEv('select-wrapper', 'focus', 'div focus');
addEv('select-wrapper', 'blur', 'div blur');
```

```css
#select-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#select-wrapper:focus {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="3 glasses">
<div id="select-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <span id="span">of</span>
  <select id="select" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="beer">Beer</option>
    <option value="wine" selected>Wine</option>
    <option value="vodka">Vodka</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="drink">
<div id="console"></div><br>
```

If you tab through the elements everything works as expected. The two input elements and the div element get focused. Same goes for clicking on the span that says "of". However if you click on the select element it gets focused instead of the div. This means that the wrong focus events become fired and the select element's visuals change just as it was focused. This is consistent among Firefox and Chrome so I assume that this is intentional.

The question is: How can I make the select element unfocusable and make the div surrounding it focusable instead? And of course I still want to be able to open the dropdown and select an option.

Comment: `tabindex` works only when you are tabbing through the elements and not on `click`

Comment: css has a `pointer-events` attribute that may help

Comment: @JaromandaX using `pointer-events: none;` makes the select element unusable as I can't select anything anymore.
Otherwise it would be a perfect solution of course.

Comment: I must not understand what you want then

Comment: if you can't focus the select, it can't be "opened"

Comment: @JaromandaX
I don't want to make the select inoperable, but I want the div element to be the one that gets focused. In my real world application the select is surround by a svg that gets styled depending on the focus state.
The user of my js library should be able to recieve focus events on the div that surrounds the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **EDIT:** This method stopped working in Firefox 52 or some earlier version

I have found a dirty solution on my own. If I ignore the fact that the select element still fires focus and blur events I could make it look like the div element becomes focused by performing `select.blur()` and `div.focus()` when the select element gets focused. See the code below.

**Notice:** If you are going to use my solution please don't forget to implement accessibility features manually since they won't work anymore as @nnnnnn pointed out.

```js
function addEv(id, event, message)
{
 document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, function(){
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += message+"<br>";
  });
}
addEv('select', 'focus', 'select focus');
addEv('select', 'blur', 'select blur');

addEv('span', 'focus', 'span focus');
addEv('span', 'blur', 'span blur');

addEv('select-wrapper', 'focus', 'div focus');
addEv('select-wrapper', 'blur', 'div blur');

document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('focus', function(){
 document.getElementById('select').blur();
  document.getElementById('select-wrapper').focus();
});
```

```css
#select-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#select-wrapper:focus {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="3 glasses">
<div id="select-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <span id="span">of</span>
  <select id="select" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="beer">Beer</option>
    <option value="wine" selected>Wine</option>
    <option value="vodka">Vodka</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input type="button" value="drink">
<div id="console"></div><br>
```

Comment: Note that this solution means your page won't meet accessibility guidelines, because it is not possible to use the select element via the keyboard. (Remember that some users can't use a mouse or other pointing device...)

Comment: I'm aware of that.
In my real world application I already implemented space key for checkboxes (which I needed to redesign in a similar way) and up and down keys for selects manually before I stumbled upon this problem (is that enough?). I only intended to show the solution of the actual issue when I wrote this answer.
However this is important enough that I will add a notice for others reading my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tabindex = -1, you can add this to the CSS property.

```
  pointer-events: none;
```

This worked for me